# Discrete-time Fourier transform of $a^{|n|} u[n]$

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dtft

I have a problem calculating the DTFT of this pair: [image]

Could anyone tell me why the DTFT for $a^{|n|} u[n]$ is different from $a^{n} u[n]$'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an obvious typo in that DTFT pair, because - as you've probably noted yourself - we clearly have $\alpha^{|n|}u[n]=\alpha^nu[n]$.

The given expression for the DTFT corresponds to the two-sided time-domain sequence $\alpha^{|n|}$, if $|\alpha|<1$ holds.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that but because the pair comes directly from a book I couldn't rule out the possibility that there's something I missed. But then, what does the "double exponential" actually mean?

Comment: @tintan: It just means that it's a two-sided sequence that has an exponentially decaying shape in both directions (note that it's a symmetric sequence).

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!